# How to setup Jenkins via API calls exclusively

Tags: docker, api, jenkins, automation

I am currently having a custom written Dockerfile which prepares a Jenkins container image with all necessary plugins I need.

There are on the other hand a lot of small steps/settings one needs to configure manually

- setup some credentials (private key) to communicate with Git provider e.g. Gitlab/Bitbucket
- approve groovy scripts when using SEED plugin
- ...

Is there a way to automate it all with API calls ?

Thx

Comment: I think the easiest way is to mount the Jenkins workspace to an external volume and reuse it when you are starting a new Jenkins container.

Comment: it would work however, If you want to make it sort of generic and in the first phase you would build a container let' say with plugins and then after startup via e.g you would trigger a series of API calls (curl, Python, ...) to configure freshly generated credentials, some tweaks in whatever "Manage Jenkins section"

Comment: check this plugin out: https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/